# Nested NuGet package dependencies not restoring correctly

Tags: .net, nuget

**Update:**

@Troopers has helped me express this question more plainly. Here it is:

- I have a class library that references a package.
- I web project references the class library.

My question: **Should the web project automatically inherit the package without referencing it explicitly?** Or does the web project have to explicitly reference the package for this to work?

---

**Original Question:**

I am having a problem getting NuGet packages to restore correctly. (At least, for my understanding of "correctly.")

I have a SLN file that includes:

```
+ TIS.sln
| + TIS.Core.Web           (A class library)
| | + Packages
| | | - NewRelic.Agent.Api (A NuGet package)
| + TIS.WCF                (A web application with a mix of WCF and WebApi)
| | + References
| | | - TIS.Core.Web       (the class library above in this SLN)
| | + Packages
| | | - Newtonsoft.Json    (A NuGet package)
| | | - Owin               (A NuGet package)
```

When I run this command line:

```
NuGet.exe restore -NonInteractive -Verbosity Detailed "C:\temp\Build\TIS.sln"
```

The NuGet packages directly referenced by the TIS.WCF project are restored (i.e., the Newtonsoft.Json and Owin packages). But the NuGet package referenced in the TIS.Core.Web project is NOT restored.

What I am expecting to happen:

1. The command should restore ALL NuGet packages in the SLN file, including any inside a class library.
2. I shouldn't have to include a direct reference to the NewRelic.Agent.Api NuGet package from TIS.WCF.sln, because I have referenced the TIS.Core.Web class library, which in turn references NewRelic.Agent.Api. So it should be downloaded as part of the NuGet restore during the build process.

Do I have any of this wrong? Is there anything that would be preventing these commands from working?

I have tried NuGet 3.3.0 and 3.5.0 (both of which are currently available on the build server) as well as NuGet 5.1.0, but the behavior is the same in each case. I'm starting to suspect that it may be working as designed, and it is my expectations that are out of line? But if that is the case, I would like confirmation of that. Also, if this isn't how it is supposed to work, what is the recommended practice here?

**Edited To Add:**

- Projects are targeting .NET Framework 4.5
- Current development is happening on the latest Visual Studio 2019, but the projects have been around for a long time and have undergone many version upgrades.

In case it matters, the folder structure is a little odd. There is a folder for the whole project. There is a folder for the SLN file inside the project folder. The TIS.WCF web application project is inside the SLN folder. But the TIS.Core.Web class library project is not -- it is in its own folder under the project folder. So:

```
+ ProjectFolder
| + SLN folder
| | - TIS.WCF project folder
| + TIS.Core.Web project folder
```

Comment: Do you use PackageRefrence in the project file or a packages.config file?

Comment: @Troopers I am using a packages.config file.

Comment: You could try to migrate to PackageReference

Comment: @Troopers Am I right that the way I have it set up should be working, if everything was working the way it is supposed to?

Comment: Not sure that the package is restored if there is no code that call code of the refrence which call the package. Othewise the package must be restored

Comment: @Troopers The class library references a package, and the web project references the class library. Should the web project automatically inherit the package without need to reference it explicitly?

Comment: The web project doesn't have to explicitly reference the package